# EMC/Exchange Powershell not running as administrator or without correct privs

Tags: permissions, exchange, powershell, emc

I have an AD/Exchange 2010 setup that usually works pretty well. However, after installing Outlook 2010 on the server and choosing to **"remember the password"** for a user who is *not* an administrator, whenever I start Exchange Management Console or Exchange PowerShell many functions are not available to me (cannot "edit") and it seems like I am connecting as the user.

Comment: I guess I'll be gentle and just say "don't do that."  Any of that.  Don't install an email client on your mail server, don't let non-admins access your mail server, and don't cache credentials on your server.  Good bet that undoing those things that shouldn't have been done in the first place will cause your problem to vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same advice as HopelessN00b:

- Do not install an e-mail client on your mail server
- Do not let non-admins access your mail server
- Do not cache credentials on your server.

To remove the "cached credentials", go to:

`Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager`

You should be able to delete them here.